# How to use max pooling to gather information from LSTM nodes

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

```
gru_out = Bidirectional(GRU(hiddenlayer_num, return_sequences=True))(embedded)
#Tensor("concat_v2_8:0", shape=(?, ?, 256), dtype=float32)
```

I use Keras to create a GRU model.I want to gather information from all the node vectors of the GRU model, instead of the last node vector.
For example, I need to get the maximum value of each vector, like the image description, but I have no idea on how to do this.
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may use [`GlobalMaxPooling1D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling1d) described here:

```
gru_out = Bidirectional(GRU(hiddenlayer_num, return_sequences=True))(embedded)
max_pooled = GlobalMaxPooling1D(gru_out)
```

Comment: Still - my answer is correct - so you could accept it and upvote it :)